# Problems integrating mercado pago on my website

Tags: reactjs, vps, mercadopago, mercadopagosdk

Iam doing a fetch to the IP of my VPS on Hostinguer, and the fetch isnt working, it seems that or the IP is wrong or i have bad setting on my VPS.
this is the function on my front end

```
 const setPreference = async () => {
        try {
            const result = await fetch('http://62.72.63.229:3001/createOrder', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ items: cartNoImg }),
            });

            console.log(result.status);

            const orderData = await result.json();
            console.log(orderData);

        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error al obtener la preferencia:', error);
        }
    };
```

this is the error

> POST http://62.72.63.229:3001/createOrder net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
> VM19:1 Error al obtener la preferencia: TypeError: Failed to fetch

I expect the payment to go well basically and to succesfully fetch the url and to can actually pay